# Laravel 5.2 Route model binding with same signature

Tags: routes, laravel-5

If I have the following two routes using route model binding where the `getRouteKeyName` property of each model has been overidden to use slug instead of id. How can laravel know which route to use?

```
Route::get('courses/{category}', function (App\Category $category) {
    return $category->name;
});

Route::get('courses/{location}', function (App\Location $location) {
    return $location->name;
});
```

test routes:

```
www.domain.com/courses/accounting

www.domain.com/courses/france
```

The second route will never be looked at since the route signature of both routes are identical?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the second route will never be fired because Laravel will takes the first route which matches.

Simply change your route to something like:

`/categories/{category}/course` and `/locations/{location}/course`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the Second route will never be looked due to the identical signature of the routes.
You can handle it in a Controller function as the slug will be available as the request parameter and you can return your result on the conditional basis of that.

```
Route::get('courses/{slug}',MyController@myfunction);
```

In your controller you can do it like this:

```
public function myfunction($slug)
{
   if($slug == "category")
   {
     $category = new \App\Category;
     return $category->name;
   }
   if($slug == "location")
   {
     $location = new \App\Location;
     return $location->name;
   }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't change a thing for the code given in the question. In fact, you wrote more lines to accomplish the exact same thing.

Comment: The solution I provided will do the job if he wants to retain the same prefix url for both of the routes. I agree that it is not an elegant solution and have more lines of code.